# User-defined ordering of model instances with unique constraint

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model which I want the user to be able to control the order of.
Here is a simplified model of what I am working with.

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

### Problem

The user will update the order field through the GUI but I can't update any of the Parameter instances as they conflict with one another through the order field.

### Example

- parameterA.order = 1 and parameterB.order = 2.
- User moves **parameterB** in front of parameterA.
- The app tries to submit the changes but parameterB can't have value 1 as it is preoccupied by parameterA and vice versa.

I have considered removing the unique constraint and in fact I have that as a fallback if another suitable solution does not present itself. But I would prefer keeping the constraint.

**Edit:**

The solution should be able to handle a large number of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the most straightforward approach would be...

Having **parameterA = 1** and **parameterB = 2**:

```
parameterA.order = -1
parameterA.save()
parameterB.order = 1
parameterB.save()
parameterA.order = 2
parameterA.save()
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that most of the time I have 100 parameters or more.